# Ubuntu shutdown leads to Cold-Boot failure

Tags: boot

I am booting a new MinisForum PC with Ubuntu 20.04.04 LTS, and have a 2nd SSD hosting Windows 10. If I shutdown the PC using Ubuntu, then any subsequent cold-boot, fails repeatedly (up to 10 times), before the PC finally starts up again.

A Cold-Boot failure is quickly detected, since the fan spins up when I press the power button, but do not spin-down as the BIOS starts to run. If the fan stays at high speed for more than 15-seconds, then I know that the cold-boot has failed. Cold-Boot failure does not end up in a BIOS screen, it's as if we never get to the BIOS.

However, if I shutdown the same PC from Windows 10, then a cold-boot (into the BIOS, Ubuntu or Windows 10) is always successful first-time. I should add that I can Restart the PC (warm-boot) using Ubuntu or Windows 10 without issue.

I don't need Windows 10 on this PC, it's only function is to ensure that I can boot the machine from cold. As such my Linux shutdown routine is to warm-boot the PC into Windows 10, and then shutdown from Windows 10.

What is Windows 10 doing upon shutdown (writing to BIOS registers etc...), that Ubuntu is not?

Comment: If what happens is exactly how you describe then there's no logical explanation (but I suspect there's more, or less, to it). In any case start by updating the firmware (UEFI "BIOS"), if available.

Comment: Hi ChanganAuto. The system behaves exactly as described. Win10 shutdown = good cold-boot, Ubuntu shutdown = bad cold-boot. There is no bios update.